# too many unnecessary directories created

Tags: sbteclipse

I'm using `sbteclipse` from the command line and getting a lot of directories I don't want -- it creates a very spammy-looking directory structure, and I want a clean structure.

```
14:59 $ find .
.
./main
./main/java
./main/scala
./main/scala/Main.scala
./main/scala-2.11
./test
./test/java
./test/scala
./test/scala-2.11
```

Why are there so many? I really only care about main/scala and that's it. And all my code is 2.11.

Comment: looks like eclipse complains when I take the 2.11 folders out. Annoying :/

Comment: okay that was fixed by reconfiguring my build path. So, my question is, why does sbteclipse make this directory structure out of the box. Which is maybe a feature and not a bug to the designers.